# Multiple col-sm-6 force reflow to the bottom

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have multiple divs with *col-sm-6* in one *row*. the setup has the first, third and consecutive divs as fairly small heights, while the second has a much larger height.

I'm expecting the divs to re-flow, with the first on the left, the second on the right and the third on the left under the first. It does this, but the top of the third div is in line with the bottom of the second. I was expecting it to move up to the bottom of the first.

```
<div class="row row-fluid">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="min-height: 30px">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="min-height: 90px">2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="min-height: 20px">3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="min-height: 40px">4</div>
</div>
```

I've constructed a jsFiddle to try to show the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/G7atf/1/

Is there a way to easliy fix this without having to write my own JS?

Comment: This is the way normal CSS works. There are several more complex solutions. Among them - [A complete guide to **Flexbox**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want *"certain elements"* on the left column and *"other elements"* on the right column, just use two columns:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
            </div>
            <!-- more items here -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
        </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
            </div>
            <!-- more items here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

If you are looking for automagically arranging your elements (AKA [Pinterest](https://www.pinterest.com/)-like layout), consider a third party solution like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) or you'll have to write your own plugin.

Comment: Thanks for that. But I should have explained: the problem is that when it collapses on xs screens, they want it to be shown in order of 1,2,3,4.

Comment: Then my answer is the final paragraph, I recommend a third party plugin.